# People picker and adduser find different person depending on Web Application on MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, user-profile

We get different people picker and add user results between web applications.

We have 3 domains in our user profile sync.

We checked user profiles and AD for a particular domainA\user3 and it looks perfect.  On one web application if I add user domainA\user3 it resolves to the correct person.  On another if I attempt to add the same domainA\user3 it resolves to domainB\user for some reason.

I checked the user is not on either web application site.

What's interesting is the user (domainA\user3 for the sake of this example) has a very common name is in all 3 domains.

domainB\user  (has no email) is the one that erroniously comes up on one web application.
domainA\user3 (the one we want)
domainC\user3 (same person on another domain)